# How to make text appear on two lines, rather than on one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like the name of the speciality, from the snapshot below, to be on 2 different lines, rather than one, as it appears quite squashed currently. Each line relates to a specific icon so would like them to also be centred directly below each. The first icon for example should be "Cardiac Electrophysiology & Ablation".

I had tried playing around with the numberOfLines and flex wrap but without much success. Thanks

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Image, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import GlobalApi from '../../Services/GlobalApi';
import Colors from '../../../assets/Shared/Colors';
import SubHeading from './SubHeading';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function Categories() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [categoryList, setCategoryList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getCategories();
}, []);

const getCategories = () => {
    GlobalApi.getCategories().then(resp => {
        setCategoryList(resp.data.data);
    });
};

if (!categoryList) {
    return null;
}

return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        <SubHeading subHeadingTitle={'Doctor Speciality'} />

        <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <FlatList
                data={categoryList}
                numColumns={5}
                columnWrapperStyle={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                }}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
                    index < 5 && (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() =>
                                navigation.navigate('hospital-doctor-list-screen', {
                                    categoryName: item.attributes.Name,
                                })
                            }
                            style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5 }}
                        >
                            <View
                                style={{
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.SECONDARY,
                                    padding: 15,
                                    borderRadius: 99,
                                }}
                            >
                                <Image
                                    source={{
                                        uri: item.attributes.Icon.data[0].attributes.url,
                                    }}
                                    style={{
                                        width: 30,
                                        height: 30,
                                    }}
                                />
                            </View>
                            <Text
                                style={{
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    marginTop: 5,
                                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                                }}
                                numberOfLines={2}
                            >
                                {item.attributes.Name}
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                }
            />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
```

}

Comment: Could you make the example reproducible and minimal? A simple way to think about it, is when you run this code somewhere, it should not have any dependency on interal things. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I'd handle this is by giving width to my Text component.

```
<Text
 style={{
  textAlign: 'center',
  marginTop: 5,
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  width: '50%' // Add width
 }}
 numberOfLines={2}>
 {item.attributes.Name}
</Text>
```